# Data Access Layer returning BusinessObjects

Tags: design-patterns, data-access-layer, business-objects

Currently I'm researching the best design pattern to implement for a windows form application using VS2010 in VB.

I'm getting a bit confused with some design patterns. I understand that the DAL should return objects and not datareaders, datasets etc. but... if I have two functions in my DAL: GetProductById & GetAllProducts

These two functions would return a Product object and a collection of Product objects respectivley. Would Product not be a BOL object?

If I add CRUD into this object then it can no longer belong to the BOL do you have two versions of the object, one for DAL & one for BLL without the database methods?

I know there are similar posts on here but they have only served to confuse me further, is it possible someone could just explain in simple terms how DAL objects interact and differ from BOL objects.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the scenario you've described is just fine- your DAL *should* return business objects (or, to use MVC terminology- model objects).
the model objects are a different 'layer', with which both the controller layer and the DA layer interact.
your CRUD methods can also go into the DAL (SaveProduct() or DeleteProduct() etc.)

Comment: OK, MVC now this is why I am confused! But I am getting there. So... my datalayer knows about my model objects and can there fore create a list of Products and return it to my controller which does what it has to do to my view... Then if I want to delete said product I would send it to a method in my DAL DeleteProduct(Product)? So I would have to create a product from the DAL and then from my controller send it back to the DAL for deletion?

Comment: all depending on the specific scenario of your application; you may also have a `DeleteProduct(int productId)` method if it makes more sense in your application. All depending on what you need.